# what does synchronization mean in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

i read that upon session.flush()

The
data will be synchronized (but not committed) when session.flush() is called

what is synchronized with what..
whether it is DB state that will come to memory by querying or
memory state will be copied to Db ?

clarify this plz..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `session.flush()` will cause SQL statements to be generated for all of the changes you have made, and those SQL statements to be executed on the database, within the sessios transaction scope.

```
Car car = (Car) session.get(Car.class, 1);
car.setModel("Mustang");
session.flush();
```

The last line will cause an `UPDATE` statement on the database. However, depending on how you handle transactions in your applications, this change might not be visible to other users before you commit the transaction held by the section.

While flushing is not really a bi-directional operation, it can be used to ensure that an auto generated identifier is assigned to a new entity object. If the `Car` class is mapped to a database table with an auto incrementing identifier, you can use flush to ensure that this identifier is available on the domain object in your application code:

```
Car car = new Car();
car.setModel("Torino");
session.save(car);

System.out.println(car.getId());               // prints 0
session.flush();
System.out.println(car.getId());               // prints something larger than 0
```

Say you want to send an email with a link to the newly created car (ok, a user account would have made more sense), but if the mail cannot be sent, you wish to rollback your transaction. Flushing the session allows you to do this.

Comment: Not getting the same scenarion........




Session is  SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[]])
Hibernate: select max(id) from EMPLOYEE
1
Hibernate: insert into EMPLOYEE (name, id) values (?, ?)
1

Comment: @abc: I am sorry, but I have no idea what your comment is all about.

Comment: i got the thing..
your code won't print "sonething larger than 0 " it will remain the same '0'

Answer (score 2):

Flushing synchronizes the  underlying persistent store with persistable state held in memory but *not* vice-versa. In other words, "in memory state is copied to the database" in the running transaction, to reuse your words. Note that flushing doesn't mean the data can't be rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

```
"Flushing is the process of synchronizing the underlying persistent
store with persistable state held in memory."
```

By default the flush mode is set to AUTO and in this case session is flushed before query execution in order to ensure that queries never return stale state.

Comment: if i do 
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
Employee emp = session.load(Employee.class,1L);
emp.setName("abc");

session.save(emp); //1
//committing transaction
tx.commit();        //2

now the DB state will be copied to memory @ which line of code ?

Comment: flushing does not copy db state to memory .It is the vice-versa.